# Installing another Python 3 version in parallel to the system one

Tags: python, python3

I need to install Python 3.7 in order to run a library that requires it, but I don't want to replace my system's native Python 3 installation (which is an earlier version) as I'm afraid to break system dependencies.

How do I install it in parallel?

Comment: Whatever you do, do not change any default python version or links. Many parts of Ubuntu must have the versions installed. You can just add any other version and then run it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to rely on a python version management tool such as [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) if it manages the python version you want.

A complete tutorial is located [here](https://www.tecmint.com/pyenv-install-and-manage-multiple-python-versions-in-linux/).

However, if you choose to do it manually (or if the version you want is not managed by **pyenv**), you might need to download it from the official site and unzip it where you want.